# Fibonacci relation formula

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

There are three numbers a,b,c such that c=a+b.
Let f(n) be n'th Fibonacci number,can we write f(a)+f(b) in terms of f(c) and c.
If yes,how?
I have tried deriving it using Binnets formula but did'nt got anything.

Comment: Observe that $1+4=2+3$, but $F_1+F_4 = 4 \neq 3 = F_2 + F_3$.

Comment: What's the source of this question?  It appears related to an active contest:  https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Answer (score 0):

$f(c) = f(a)f(b+1)+f(a-1)f(b)$, so the answer to your question is not quite. Generally, $f(a+b)$ is much larger than $f(a)+f(b)$.

Comment: I know this one.But is there something like f(a)+f(b) = x*f(c) + y or something like that?

Comment: I think you want $x$ and $y$ to be independent of $a$ and $b$. If that is what you want, then it's impossible because that would imply $f(a)+f(b) = f(a-1)+f(b+1)=...$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ an depend only on $c$ i.e $a$ + $b$.